# Use Google Map API for tbt navigation with voice controls

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am writing an app where I want to guide user from its current location on the map to a specific point. How can I use the Google Map API for turn by turn navigation with voice controls in my android app for this?
Can I launch Google Navigation from my app and pass location information to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to open the Google map app.

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+startLat+","+startLong+"&daddr="+endLat+","+endLong;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks Chronos. I am getting current location update after every one second using GPS (kind of satnav thing). Will this solution works in this scenario.

Comment: This solution works if you want Start and Finish points. You can view the path on google map and you can switch to navigation app.
But if you want to update the map every one second you need to draw the lines and point on the map.

Comment: Switching to navigation mode solved issue. But I am still not quite sure about voice controls. I did testing on emulator but do not know if turn by turn voice controls work in emulator.